# [Groovy] How to link /scan to base_link?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-link, move-base, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch my move_base.launch, ( http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) , I got this error :

```
Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: 
[ WARN] [1406541885.908819812]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1406541885.908702 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
```

This is my   frames.pdf file

[image: image description]

This is the rqt_graph :

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187967/%5Bgroovy%5D-how-to-link-/scan-to-base_link?/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-28**:
did you run roslaunch my_robot_configuration.launch first ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
yes I did.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-28**:
check if tf is available using
$ rosrun tf view_frames
$ evince frames.pdf

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
I've posted the result

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-28**:
check laser is published on /scan topic. otherwise remap your laser topic to /scan. please upload picture of rqt_graph .

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
When I make rostopic echo /scan I see that somethink is published

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-28**:
you can see that /odom is not subscribe by none.  No idea about it.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
No, I don't know how to link /odom to base_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey !

You need to publish the TF between odom and map. Not on the topic, the actual [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) (check out the wiki for more information on it).

For a direct answer, in a launch file, use those lines of code :

```
<!-- Run a static transform between /odom and /map -->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_map_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100" />
```

They will launch a node named `odom_map_broadcaster` that will publish a constant transform between /map and /odom. Here I suppose they are at the same place at first. Hope this help.

The laser scan is a warning only, it means tf is waiting for it (probably because you told move_base to use it) and you actually don't publish the transform for now. Understand that, even though you publish on the topic, what you miss here is the tf transform.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
But I don't have the package tf
I tried to git clone https://github.com/ros/geometry.git but when I catekin_make, i got too much error

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
Moreover, I tried to add your command in my launch file and it said
cannot launch node of type [tf/static_transform_publisher]: can't locate node [static_transform_publisher] in package [tf]

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-07-29**:
Why don't you `sudo apt-get install` the tf package then ? But according to your second comment it seems like you have it. Could you edit your question to add those information : Do you have the tf package (in the depot, no need to git clone) ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
No, I didn't manage to do it in groovy, so yesterday I installed a second distro, hydro, in which i managed to install, but it still doesn't work. So if in groovy you have the solution, I'm still ready to take it. Thank you

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
I groovy when i maid sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-tf it said there is any package of this name

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-07-29**:
That solution work with groovy and hydro. Try `apt-cache search ros-groovy-tf` to search for the package to install. TO make sure it's install use `dkpg -l | grep tf`

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
It found this in apt-cache search ros-groovy-tf

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
ros-groovy-tf2-geometry-msgs - tf2_geometry_msgs
ros-groovy-tf2-kdl - KDL binding for tf2
ros-groovy-tf2-msgs - tf2_msgs
ros-groovy-tf2-ros - This package contains the ROS bindings for the tf2 library, for both Python and C++.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
ros-groovy-tf2-tools - tf2_tools
ros-groovy-tf2-web-republisher - Republishing of Selected TFs

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-01**:
I only have tf2, not tf, is-it the error?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-08-02**:
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2 and read about it. Tf2 is the new tf so it's good use this